# Please can you explain to my son and me how to solve this factorisation: $(a-b)^2 - 2(a-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(a-b)^2-2(a-b)$

Please explain how to factor this expression.  My son and I are stuck as we don't know how they come to the answer.

Comment: This seems to be $$(a-b)^2-2(a-b)=(a-b)(a-b-2)$$where both terms have a factor of $(a-b)$ that can be factored out.

Comment: Use $ab+ac=a(b+c).$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  If we let $d = a - b$, this expression has the form $d^2 - 2d = d(d - 2)$, where we extract the common factor of $d$.  Substituting $a - b$ for $d$ gives the answer Peter Foreman provided in the first comment.

Comment: $A^2-2A=A\cdot A -2A=A(A-2)$(check this). Set $A=a-b$, then $(a-b)^2-2(a-b)=(a-b)((a-b)-2).$

Answer (score 4):

For more complex equations like this one, it can help to use an intermediate variable. Here we can use $$a-b=X$$

Now we can rewrite the initial equation as follows $$(a-b)^2-2(a-b) = X^2-2X$$

Hopefully you can easily spot that this can be factorised as $$X(X-2)=(a-b)(a-b-2)$$